# Django - ForeignKey value same as object from different model

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two models. One of them have a ForeignKey which should be related to an object in a different model:

```
class Game(models.Model):
    gameday = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    hometeam1 = models.ForeignKey(Teams, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="hometeam1", blank=True, null=True)
    
class Tipp(models.Model):
    hometeam1   = models.ForeignKey(Game, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=Game.hometeam1)
    week = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
```

The hometeam1 object in the model Tipp should be the same as Game.hometeam1 and Game.hometeam1 gets his value manually. How can I assign that Tipp.hometeam1 has everytime the same value as Game.hometeam1?

Comment: you know concept of ForeignKey

Comment: I think so, why?